# How to get rid of 'else' after 'guard' condition error in Swift?

Tags: swift, syntax, compiler-errors, project

I'm following a tutorial on youtube on how to create a Pokedex in Swift. I'm following all the same steps and my file arrangement is the same but I can't get rid of this stupid error.

```
 URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        guard let pokemon = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Pokemon].self, from: data)
```

I'm getting an error on the third line

Comment: Could you also post the error message?

Comment: What do you want to happen if the second guard fails?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't showing the rest of your statement, but here's what I can infer is happening:

Every `guard` statement has to be in this format:

```
guard *CONDITION* else {
  //some code
  return //or otherwise leave the current scope
}
```

You have the `guard` and the condition, but you're probably not following it with else. Like the statement above, it should look something like (note the `else` at the end of the line):

```
guard let pokemon = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Pokemon].self, from: data) else {
  //do something to handle the error
  return
}
```

The documentation for `guard` can be found on this page: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Statements.html

Leo Dabus in the comments points out that it would be good to have a more robust solution to the decoding. You may want to replace your `guard` statement with something along these lines:

```
do {
 let pokemon = try JSONDecoder().decode([Pokemon].self, from: data)
} catch { 
 //handle the error
 print(error)
}
```

In this scenario, you have access to `error`, which would give you some information as to why the decoding failed, whereas using the `try?` and `guard` statement, it could fail mysteriously.

Comment: Well this is very bad practice while decoding a json string. OP should use `do` `try` `catch` pattern, handle the error and get rid of the `try?` and the `guard` statement.

Comment: I agree with you, but my top priority was explaining the compiler error. In the context of the question, it seems like that's a reasonable approach. I will edit my answer to also include a better practice for it.